# Silex: documentation's folder structure

Tags: documentation, structure, directory, silex

I've been working with Silex a few times now. And I like it, but sometimes, the documentation confuses me simply because they use another folder structure.

Who can tell me which folder structure they use exactly in Silex 2.0?
[Documentation](https://silex.symfony.com/doc/2.0/)

```
├── composer.json
├── composer.lock
├── vendor
│   └── ...
└── web
    └── index.php
```

Where are the views, controllers etcetera stored?

Comment: https://github.com/silexphp/Silex-Skeleton, https://www.google.com/search?q=silex+skeleton

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Silex is not a "convention over configuration" framework: it does not prescribe nor care what the structure of your file system or application organisation is; that is why there's no mention of such things in the docs.

Just organise things the way that best suits your own needs.

Answer (score 2):

Just for example, a directory structure I usually use.

```
├── config
│   └── dev.php
│   └── test.php
│   └── ... 
├── src                        PSR-4 compatible directory structure
│   └── Component              Customized components (Symfony's components or any other)
│       └── Security
│           └── ...
│       └── Validator
│           └── ...     
│       └── ...  
│   └── Controller
│   └── DataFixtures
│   └── Migrations
│   └── Provider               My service providers
│   └── Serivice               My services
│       └── Auth
│           └── ...
│       └── Registration
│           └── ...
│       └── ...     
│   └── Application.php        Customized Silex application class
├── tests
├── var
│   └── cache
│   └── log
│   └── ...
├── vendor
│   └── ...
├── web
│   └── index.php
│   └── index-test.php
├── composer.json
├── composer.lock
```

And my [implementation on GitHub](https://github.com/sky003/silex-user). It's currently WIP, but you can use it as a boilerplate for your Silex application.